# Confidence interval for the variance of exponential distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

I know that if $X \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\theta)$, and $Y=\theta X \implies Y \sim \operatorname{Exp}(1)$.

I want a confidence interval for $E(X)= \frac{1}{\theta}$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X)= \frac{1}{\theta^2}$

The confidence interval for the mean is: $P(a<Y<b)=1-\alpha \implies P(a<\theta X<b)=1-\alpha $
And then $P(\frac{X}{b}<\frac{1}{\theta}<\frac{X}{a})=1-\alpha$.

Can I do this? : $P((\frac{X}{b})^2<(\frac{1}{\theta})^2<(\frac{X}{a})^2)=1-\alpha \ $  is a confidence interval for the variance.

I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: So you're only interested in developing a confidence interval from a sample of size $n=1$, is that correct?

Comment: In general if we have $X_1,X_2,..,X_n$ random variables.

Comment: An unbiased estimator for $\frac{1}{\theta^2}$ is $\frac{X_1^2+\dots+X_n^2}{2n}$. When $n$ is large the distribution of this unbiased estimator can be approximated using a normal distribution. Are you assuming $n$ is large (i.e. at least $30$)?

Comment: The problem is: Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ a random sample of $Exponential(\theta)$.  Find a confidence interval at level $1-\alpha$ for the mean and the variance.

Comment: In order to find a confidence interval you first need to establish a point estimate for whatever it is you're estimating. There are many different point estimates for the mean and variance. The maximum likelihood estimator is a standard first choice for your point estimates, which, in your problem, is $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{X}^2$ respectively. Do you know how to derive these?

Comment: I need to find a confidence interval for the mean and variance of the population, i.e. $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{\theta} \quad Var(X_i)=\frac{1}{\theta^2}$, and I know that the maximum likelihood estimator is $\theta = \frac{1}{ \bar{X} }$.

Comment: Do you know how to show that the MLE of $\frac{1}{\theta}$ and $\frac{1}{\theta^2}$ are $\bar{X}$ and ${\bar{X}}^2$ respectively? That's a good place to start.

Comment: I know that $L(X_1,...,X_n; \theta)= \prod \theta \exp (- \theta x_i)= \theta^n \exp(- \theta \sum x_i) $ and I need to get the derivative of $ln(L;\theta)$ and I obtain $\hat{\theta}= \frac{1}{\bar{X}} \ $ and then  $ \ \frac{1}{\theta}= \bar{X} \quad \frac{1}{\theta^2}= \bar{X}^2$

Comment: Let rate $\lambda = 1/\theta = 1/6,$ so the exponential mean and SD are $6.$ Let $A$ be the sum of $n = 50$ observations. Then $A/\theta \sim\mathsf{Gamma}(n,n).$ Pivot to get 95% CI for $\theta$ of form $(A/U, A/L),$ where $L, U$ cut 2.5% from lower and upper tails, respective. Take the square of endpoints to get CI for variance.  In R, code `set.seed(2022);  a = mean(rexp(50, 1/6)); CI = a/qgamma(c(.975,.025), 50,50); CI^2` returns $(19.17705.\, 58.43421)$ as CI for variance. // Or convert gamma to chi-sq dist'n and use printed tables.

Comment: If you follow my comment, please feel free to fill in details and gaps to use it for your own Answer to your question. But fix typo: $A$ is sample mean (as in code), not sum. // My CI uses exact dist'n even for small $n.$ For exponential data, you won't get an accurate result using a normal approximation unless $n$ is quite large.